# Unable to display output in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a list of items and on button click it should display more information on that particular item. For this, I have created one hook that gets the list of all the items from API and displays the list as it iterates inside a `<ul>` tag. (this is inside the return tag.) On each iteration it shows a button called "Details"

```
<button onClick ={moreInfo.bind(this, post)} >Details</button>
```

and when that is clicked it sends the information on that object from the list to the following code -

```
const moreInfo = (index) => {

         console.log(index.name) //works

          return (  <div> 
                {index.map = ( x => (
                    <div>{x.name}</div>
                    ))} 
             </div>) //no output
       }
```

console.log is displaying the name but nothing displays via return tag here

Comment: `moreInfo` is not a hook, it's a click event handler. Since your component never returns the return value from your click handler, it never displays. Also you're printing a `name` property of the `index` object and in the next line you try to iterate over the object like it's an array. There's a lot that's going wrong here...

Comment: HI Tobias I ment to say that i created a hook and that fetches data from an API. this code is not included above.  The code above is only for the button and what data is being passed to the event handler.

Comment: Oh my bad, I read to quickly! :) What I wrote despite the hook still applies though.

Comment: Index is an object that has name, id, type values. I was trying to output only the name for now

Comment: Yes, the `map` is used to map values from an array to different values. Since you're dealing with an object that won't work. If you just want to return the name change it to: `return <div>{index.name}</div>;`. However then it will still not work correctly since you're returning the JSX from your click handler.

Comment: I have tried to return <div> {index.name} </div> but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Also tried to create another hook but with the same data but not sure how to call it. totally confused how t proceed

Comment: Could you maybe post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Just spin up a CodeSandbox and include the relevant code there. You don't have to include the API part, just work with constants as data.

Comment: Here is link to CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-hamilton-erkqv?fontsize=14

Comment: The Sandbox you posted doesn't run. I fixed it for you: [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/flamboyant-goldberg-d79il). Please note if you post something like this, leave out the API part and use constant data, also make sure that it runs. Now that it "works", what is it supposed to do, when you click on the button?

Comment: Thanks Tobias, but i felt that if you could add an API link (like any to the code i had) maybe we could have found the exact output. Well I am trying to output some details from API when moreinfo button is clicked..like name,street for example

Answer (score 0):

You are not mapping thought the array, you are just assigning `map` property to the `index` variable
Try do that, like this:

```
const MoreInfo = (index) => {
    return (  
        <div> 
            {index.map(x => <div>{x.name}</div>)} 
        </div>
    ) 
}
```

Comment: That's correct, but it still won't render correctly, since the JSX is returned from the click handler.